# delete from a associated model

Tags: php, cakephp

I've 2 models: **Photo** and **Score**. Each `Photo` has a `Score`.
`Photo` is connect to `Score` by `$hasOne = array('Score')`.

I want to delete photo score, when the photo is deleted.

How to do it in Cake?

(Note: I use `deleteAll` for delete photos)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set the association as dependent.
See http://book.cakephp.org/view/1043/hasMany.